# Override variable in different controller Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used ng-show="splash" and for my first splash but the loader come out even when I'm in my second controller. Why? I try to set it to false but it seem doesn't work.

My secondCtrl only active when the $state is actived.

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

      $scope.splash = true;

}]);

app.controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
     $scope.splash2 = true;
     $scope.splash = false;

}]);
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. Could you explain what you're trying to achieve, and show the related html?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8850/).

I have an example of nested controllers and an example of siblings.  They both work as expected.

**controllers:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.splash = true
}

function MyCtrl2($scope) {
    $scope.splash = false;   
}
```

**partials:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p ng-show="splash">Splash 1</p>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
        <p ng-show="splash">Splash 2</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p ng-show="splash">Splash3</p>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
    <p ng-show="splash">Splash 4</p>
</div>
```